# shallow() fails because of RSTTraversal unavailable

Tags: javascript, npm, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to get started with jest and doing snapshot tests. I have actually had this working in the past, I came and saw the below error, so i proceeded to read around and upgrade packages where I could, but still I am getting the error.

**Splash.test.js**

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import shallowToJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import Splash from './Splash';

it('Splash page is rendered', () => {
    const result = shallow(
        <Splash />,
    );

    expect(shallowToJson(result)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

**Terminal Output**

```
> jest

 FAIL  src/components/Splash/Splash.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'enzyme/build/RSTTraversal' from 'shallow.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:194:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme-to-json/shallow.js:15:21)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.83s
Ran all test suites.
```

**Large Package.json**

```
{
  ....
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
    "react": "^15.5.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.5.0",
    "react-css-modules": "^4.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router-page-transition": "^3.0.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.5.4",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
    ......
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ......
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-jest": "^22.0.6",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^2.7.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^3.3.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-require": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-stateless-component-name": "^1.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.0",
    "jest": "^22.0.6",
    "jest-cli": "^22.0.6",
    "jest-enzyme": "^4.0.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.7",
    "redux-actions": "^2.2.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-form": "^6.7.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.0",
    "redux-persist": "^4.8.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.0",
    "require-hacker": "^3.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.0",
    "svg-react-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack-config": "^7.0.0",
    "webpack-dashboard": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
  },
  ......
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./node_modules/jest-enzyme/lib/index.js",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
      "<rootDir>/app/"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
        "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
      }
    },
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this same error when I have a version mis-match between my enzyme and enzyme-to-json. You either need to upgrade enzyme or downgrade enzyme-to-json.

I currently have two different combinations working in different projects:

enzyme 2.8.2 & enzyme-to-json 1.5.0

enzyme 3.3.0 & enzyme-to-json 3.3.0

Comment: Please could you give the version numbers you're currently using for it to work.

Comment: added above in answer

Comment: using versions 3.3.0 fro answer still gives the problem. Using React Native.
(enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.1.1)
peer dep missing: enzyme@^2.7.1, required by enzyme-to-json@1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your `shallowToJson` import to:

```
import { shallowToJson } from 'enzyme-to-json';
```

Comment: I like our thinking, but doing it my way would return undefined. So I have the same error with ur way I'm afraid